# Souncloud to mp3 converter - Soundcloud has changed the system, my script doesn't work now

Tags: php, mp3, converters, soundcloud

I've a website that convert soundcloud links to mp3, but recently, they changed their system, so my script doesn't work anymore :(

my script is simple :

```
$url = file_get_contents($link);
$url = str_replace('\u0026amp;', '&', $url);
preg_match_all('#title":"([^"]*)"#i', $url, $titles); //search for the song titles
preg_match_all('#streamUrl":"([^"]*)"#i', $url, $streamUrls); //search for the stream/download urls
```

The soundcloud link is $url
The titles were in $titles variable, and the links in $streamUrls.

But now, I can't use the file_get_content function with the soundcloud pages, I have an error "400".

Anyone have an other WORKING solution ?

(for information, anything2mp3.com can do that, so there is a solution ^^)

Answer (score 2):

New answer:

I'm not great at PHP, but you're probably going to want something like this

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fmsmrsounds%2Fms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix&client_id=[your client_id]'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data["operacion"];
echo $data["stream_url"];

$file = $data["stream_url"] .= '?client_id=[your client_id]'; 
echo $file;
header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file)); 
readfile($file);
?>
```

Old answer:

Here is a small Python script I wrote to download the 128kpbs joint stereo streaming MP3 from any SoundCloud URL for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825590/replace-filename-mp3-when-downloading/25855778) StackOverflow question.

```
import json, requests

url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json'

your_client_id = '[PUT YOUR client_id HERE]'

params = dict(
    url='https://soundcloud.com/msmrsounds/ms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix',
    client_id=your_client_id,
)

# resolve
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = json.loads(resp.text)

# get api url
track_url = data.get('location')

track_resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
track_data = json.loads(resp.text)

# get stream_url

track_title = track_data.get('title')

stream_url = track_data.get('stream_url')

print track_title
print stream_url

stream_params = dict(
    client_id=your_client_id,
)

stream_resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)

# pass in title + '.mp3' for filename
with open(track_title + '.mp3', 'wb') as handle:
    response = requests.get(url=stream_url, params=stream_params, stream=True)

    if not response.ok:
        # Something went wrong
        print 'Error downloading mp3'

    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break

        handle.write(block)
```

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/JALsnipe/Python-Fun/tree/master/SoundCloud-Downloader)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using PHP and I don't have any know of python :(
But I've found a solution for getting the stream_url via the Soundcloud API, now I want to use a php script with header() for downloading from stream_url, but this doesn't work, still searching...

Comment: Then you should have specified the language in the question and used the ```php``` tag.

Comment: @user3768981 I edited my answer to include some hacky PHP I just wrote.  My PHP isn't great, but I wanted to provide some solution for you.

Comment: Thank you, this method look like my old method, but now the file_get_contents() function is blocked by souncdloud, it returns a 400 error code :( 
But now with the API and some jquery code, I can get the stream link, I'm working on my project for downloading correctly from this stream link ;)

Comment: @user3768981 I am able to use the `file_get_contents()` method just fine in the code snippet I posted in my answer.  A 400 error code means Bad Request, most likely due to a programming error.  I'd double check your code and HTTP request.  If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks.