# SoundCloud uploads from iOS have incorrect download file name

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I'm using the iOS API to upload wav files to SoundCloud.  There's no problem with the upload, however, when I attempt to download the file on the SoundCloud website the file name is always "unknown".  When I upload the same song from my computer the file name matches the title.

There's nothing in the API reference that indicates you can set the download file name, so I assume it's generated from the title.  Is this correct?  Is there any additional metadata that needs to be set to make this work?

Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the `stream_url` mp3 filename?  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825590/replace-filename-mp3-when-downloading.  Otherwise, the name of the actual downloadable file is the name used by the original uploaded file.

Comment: Ok, the fact that the downloadable file name is the same as the original file name is what I needed to know.  I'm actually using an NSData object and, after some digging, I see that the OAuth2Client library just hardcodes "unknown" as the file name in the HTTP header.  Switching to an NSURL should fix my problem.  Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Posted, let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downloading a sound file from the SoundCloud website, the filename the user sees is the one used by the original uploader when they uploaded the sound to SoundCloud.